# How to write this code without using classes?

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

I'm having trouble deleting classes that are used in this code. This is a code that I found online, and it is a 2d car physics simulator. I tried just deleting the lines of code where it defines those classes, but it won't work because the class is used in code and I don't know how to get rid of it. Thank you in advance.

I would like to have this code work without using classes Car and Game.

```
import os
import pygame
from math import sin, radians, degrees, copysign
from pygame.math import Vector2
class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, angle=0.0, length=4, max_steering=30, max_acceleration=5.0):
        self.position = Vector2(x, y)
        self.velocity = Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.angle = angle
        self.length = length
        self.max_acceleration = max_acceleration
        self.max_steering = max_steering
        self.max_velocity = 20
        self.brake_deceleration = 10
        self.free_deceleration = 2

        self.acceleration = 0.0
        self.steering = 0.0

    def update(self, dt):
        self.velocity += (self.acceleration * dt, 0)
        self.velocity.x = max(-self.max_velocity, min(self.velocity.x, self.max_velocity))

        if self.steering:
            turning_radius = self.length / sin(radians(self.steering))
            angular_velocity = self.velocity.x / turning_radius
        else:
            angular_velocity = 0

        self.position += self.velocity.rotate(-self.angle) * dt
        self.angle += degrees(angular_velocity) * dt
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Car tutorial")
        width = 1280
        height = 720
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ticks = 60
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "car.png")
        car_image = pygame.image.load(image_path)
        car = Car(0, 0)
        ppu = 32

        while not self.exit:
            dt = self.clock.get_time() / 1000

            # Event queue
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.exit = True

            # User input
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                if car.velocity.x < 0:
                    car.acceleration = car.brake_deceleration
                else:
                    car.acceleration += 1 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                if car.velocity.x > 0:
                    car.acceleration = -car.brake_deceleration
                else:
                    car.acceleration -= 1 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if abs(car.velocity.x) > dt * car.brake_deceleration:
                    car.acceleration = -copysign(car.brake_deceleration, car.velocity.x)
                else:
                    car.acceleration = -car.velocity.x / dt
            else:
                if abs(car.velocity.x) > dt * car.free_deceleration:
                    car.acceleration = -copysign(car.free_deceleration, car.velocity.x)
                else:
                    if dt != 0:
                        car.acceleration = -car.velocity.x / dt
            car.acceleration = max(-car.max_acceleration, min(car.acceleration, car.max_acceleration))

            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                car.steering -= 30 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                car.steering += 30 * dt
            else:
                car.steering = 0
            car.steering = max(-car.max_steering, min(car.steering, car.max_steering))

            # Logic
            car.update(dt)

            # Drawing
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, car.angle)
            rect = rotated.get_rect()
            self.screen.blit(rotated, car.position * ppu - (rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2))
            pygame.display.flip()

            self.clock.tick(self.ticks)
        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

This is the link of the original code: http://rmgi.blog/pygame-2d-car-tutorial.html

Comment: Why do you want to remove the classes? Are you sure that you need to remove them?

Comment: Well, I want to, but only if it's possible. Can I make the code work by removing the Game class and keeping the Car class? I still haven't learned anything about classes and I'm looking for a solution without them

Comment: Yeah, you can, but delete the class Keyword it's not enough, you must refactor the run method. I advise you to learn a bit of oop in python, it's quite simple, don't worry.

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, this should be a nice intro to oop in python https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 0):

Solely as an academic exercise, here is the same code without classes. A dictionary is used to hold the car properties. Note that the class syntax is cleaner than the dictionary syntax.

The important thing to note is that the car code is no longer encapsulated. The `updatecar` function is now part of the main code instead of being isolated to the car object. Since this code is small, encapsulation is not a major concern, but if the car had a dozen methods than the code could quickly become messy and difficult to maintain.

All this said, it's definitely important that you learn about classes and OOP. It will save you some pain in the future.

```
import os
import pygame
from math import sin, radians, degrees, copysign
from pygame.math import Vector2

def buildcar(x, y, angle=0.0, length=4, max_steering=30, max_acceleration=5.0):
    car = {}  # dictionary of properties
    car["position"] = Vector2(x, y)
    car["velocity"] = Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
    car["angle"] = angle
    car["length"] = length
    car["max_acceleration"] = max_acceleration
    car["max_steering"] = max_steering
    car["max_velocity"] = 20
    car["brake_deceleration"] = 10
    car["free_deceleration"] = 2
    car["acceleration"] = 0.0
    car["steering"] = 0.0
    return car

def updatecar(car, dt):
    car["velocity"] += (car["acceleration"] * dt, 0)
    car["velocity"].x = max(-car["max_velocity"], min(car["velocity"].x, car["max_velocity"]))

    if car["steering"]:
        turning_radius = car["length"] / sin(radians(car["steering"]))
        angular_velocity = car["velocity"].x / turning_radius
    else:
        angular_velocity = 0

    car["position"] += car["velocity"].rotate(-car["angle"]) * dt
    car["angle"] += degrees(angular_velocity) * dt


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Car tutorial")
width = 1280
height = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
ticks = 60
exit = False


current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "dotyellow.png")
car_image = pygame.image.load(image_path)
car = buildcar(0,0) 
ppu = 32

while not exit:
    dt = clock.get_time() / 1000

    # Event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True

    # User input
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        if car["velocity"].x < 0:
            car["acceleration"] = car["brake_deceleration"]
        else:
            car["acceleration"] += 1 * dt
    elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        if car["velocity"].x > 0:
            car["acceleration"] = -car["brake_deceleration"]
        else:
            car["acceleration"] -= 1 * dt
    elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if abs(car["velocity"].x) > dt * car["brake_deceleration"]:
            car["acceleration"] = -copysign(car["brake_deceleration"], car["velocity"].x)
        else:
            car["acceleration"] = -car["velocity"].x / dt
    else:
        if abs(car["velocity"].x) > dt * car["free_deceleration"]:
            car["acceleration"] = -copysign(car["free_deceleration"], car["velocity"].x)
        else:
            if dt != 0:
                car["acceleration"] = -car["velocity"].x / dt
    car["acceleration"] = max(-car["max_acceleration"], min(car["acceleration"], car["max_acceleration"]))

    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        car["steering"] -= 30 * dt
    elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        car["steering"] += 30 * dt
    else:
        car["steering"] = 0
    car["steering"] = max(-car["max_steering"], min(car["steering"], car["max_steering"]))

    # Logic
    updatecar(car, dt)

    # Drawing
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, car["angle"])
    rect = rotated.get_rect()
    screen.blit(rotated, car["position"] * ppu - (rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2))
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(ticks)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I needed!